# Kubernetes Node 14 pod restarts and terminated with exit code 0

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, angular-universal

I have an Angular Universal application with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app
COPY dist/webapp /app/dist/webapp

ENV NODE_ENV "production"
ENV PORT 80

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve:ssr"]
```

And I can deploy it to a Kubernetes cluster just fine but it keeps getting restarted every 10 minutes or so:

```
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
api-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx       1/1     Running   0          48m
webapp-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx   1/1     Running   232        5d19h
```

Pod logs are clean and when I describe the pod I just see:

```
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Tue, 22 Sep 2020 15:58:27 -0300
      Finished:     Tue, 22 Sep 2020 16:20:31 -0300

Events:
  Type    Reason   Age                      From                           Message
  ----    ------   ----                     ----                           -------
  Normal  Created  3m31s (x233 over 5d19h)  kubelet, pool-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx  Created container webapp
  Normal  Started  3m31s (x233 over 5d19h)  kubelet, pool-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx  Started container webapp
  Normal  Pulled   3m31s (x232 over 5d18h)  kubelet, pool-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx  Container image "registry.gitlab.com/..." already present on machine
```

This is my deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: $CI_PROJECT_NAME
  namespace: $KUBE_NAMESPACE
  labels:
    app: webapp
    tier: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
       maxSurge: 0
       maxUnavailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp
      tier: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: gitlab-registry
      containers:
        - name: $CI_PROJECT_NAME
          image: $IMAGE_TAG
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

How can I tell the reason it keeps restarting? Thanks!

Comment: Does that Dockefile work for you locally?

Comment: also I think you don't commit your `dist/webapp` , so you should build it when you are building your docker image.
You should add `npm install` and `npm run build:ssr` or `npm run build:universal` where it needed.

Comment: the dockerfile is working both locally and in production! it also works in the cluster without any problem for 10 minutes or so and then it restarts without errors

Comment: can you check `kubectl get events` ?

Comment: also if you are using node 14 , you are using universe version 10 and up right?
Also, I would suggest to lock on a specific node 14 version and not `14-alpine`, let's say `14.11.0-alpine` or though, a version you can trust that does not crash with your version of the universe.

Comment: `kubectl get events` returns the same info as stated in `describe pod`: Created, Started and no errors.. I'm using `"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.1.1",` in my package.json

Comment: you think I should downgrade node?

Comment: If anyone comes to this place, it was a memory leak caused by subscriptions not closed correctly

Comment: Hi @JoaquínL.Robles , In my case I am using node node:16-slim , I hav checked K8 logs , there is nothing like memory leak in logs , is there any workaround to reproduce Or cause other than memory elak ?

Comment: Maybe you can describe the deployment to know the causes why the pod was deleted